# Css selector if a child or grandchild is given a particular class

Tags: css

I am working on a list application - and I need to hook into the parent selector if the child/grandchild is given an active class.

```
<div class="checkbox-click-drop-wrapper">
   <div class="checkbox-click-drop">
     <div class="checkbox-click-drop-group edit-order-mode">           
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

so when edit-order-mode is on the child --- I need to select the grandparent and override css styles

is there a way to do this?

Comment: Yes, but I believe you will need JavaScript in order to check what class is currently on your child element and then do a condition around that.

Comment: It can't be done with plain `CSS` or `CSS3` until `CSS4`

Comment: I'm using ember -- to append the class back to the grand parent - can be done how?

Comment: There's a way if you can change your HTML, is there a reason you don't?

Comment: its nested and recursive

Comment: So you have free reign and no CMS restrictions?

Comment: yes - pretty much - but its far more complex that it is - and its ember

Comment: Is the child's classes changed by a click event or programmatically?

Comment: via ember - yes -- I am unsure how to propagate back up to the root parent

Comment: @mbharanidharan88 I've checked the CSS4 selectors but still not able to find parent selector. Where did you get that info?

Comment: @StarLight, It was [proposed](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-selectors4-20110929/) but it seems the document is outdated now

Comment: So there's no way to assign a class to both tags? Like have the grandparent and grandchild have a class that they only share and when that condition is triggered just target that special class? Like `.edit-order-mode` is assigned to both tags but they have different rules dependent upon whether it's the elder or younger?

Comment: I'm trying to use a computed variable to detect the change

Comment: When the change happens the user us not involved and there's no events?

Comment: I fixed it with the computed variable -- its a nested recursive ember application - tricky to append the class at the right place